# Facebook signed_request in my web page

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

Is possible to access to the signed_request data in my web page? (out of Facebook enviroment)

Comment: what you mean by singed request? the one being sent to FB for getting authorization code and access_token?

Comment: The signed_request that I mentioned is referenced in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JavaScript SDK for login on your site (FB.login/FB.getLoginStatus), then you’ll get a signed_request property in the response.authResponse object.